# How do I change language in my Navigation/CD/DVD System?

Tags: navigation

I am using a Toyota Noah 2009 Model Micro. Inside the Car there is a Navigation/CD/DVD System Model NHDT W59G 36064, but it is equipped in Japanese Language and I am not familiar with this.

Could you please help me to change the language to English fro Japanese?

Answer (score 1):

Does it look like this? This is the closest thing I can find: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPgmnj_kSng

If that doesn't help, I would take photos and find someone to help translate what the labels are (I doubt you'll find that sort of help on this site).

You can also try something like the Google Translate application. It allows you to take photos and translate them instantly on your smartphone.

Android: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.translate

iOS: https://itunes.apple.com/ie/app/google-translate/id414706506